# PHP move_uploaded_file not working, like the file doesn't upload in the tmp folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a "strange" problem about the move_uploaded_file in PHP.

*I read all the problem and answer about problems like mine on stackoverflow but none of them answer my problem*.

The curious thing is : it's like if the temp file is never created in the tmp folder, so when I call the move_uploaded_file it's the line who "bugged".
I want to said that in my code I ran through all the "IF" clause and the variable $uploadOk tells me that everything is ok and I can upload my file.

Here's the code :
In my form :

```
<form action="enregistrement.php?act=<?PHP echo $methode ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<button type='submit' class='btn-post'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you see the method (POST) and enctype (multipart/form-data) are good.

in the "enregistrement.php" page :

```
$uploadOk = 1;
$target_file = "";
function SaveAvatar(&$uploadOk, &$target_file){
    $target_dir = "/assets/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userAvatar"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["userAvatar"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        //echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        //$uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["userAvatar"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    echo($_FILES["userAvatar"]["tmp_name"]);
    echo(  "::" );
    echo($target_file);
    exit;
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userAvatar"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["userAvatar"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }   
}
```

**FIRST: I try some ECHO to validate variables.

## 1- The variable $uploadOk is equal to 1, So the file , the size, etc are good.

## 2- I have the right to upload , write and create in my temps file. Also my php.ini have the: file_uploads = On

## 3- My directories are good. The result of the echo gives me the good path.

## 4- My upload directory exist and have all the rights. the php.ini =  upload_tmp_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"**

**The only thing is when I run the program I never see is I let my file browser open in my tmp directory, and until the program stop with the EXIT, I never see an upload file in this directory, just see the Session files.**

Does one of you see something that I missed ?
thanks

Comment: just a cursory look, it looks like there are several places you code can fail silently.

Comment: That said, (i see you know you have `exit` in there) I wouldn't  stress to much if it doesn't show up in the `tmp` folder, are you sure you are looking in the right place?  You can check in `phpinfo()` for this `upload_tmp_dir` that will tell you where the uploads go.  This may or may not be the same place as the session tmp location.

Comment: Can you explain. Because I get the code on w3schools and it runs ok until the last line . Thanks ! About the tmp folder like I write it at point #4, it's the c:/wamp64/tmp . Also I write an EXIT to be sure to stay on this page and validate my variables. Just remove this Exit and I block on the line : if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userAvatar"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))

Comment: @Mikey - that's what I thought, `and until the program stop with the EXIT,` but the OP knows that, I think its a question of `I never see an upload file in this directory`

Comment: Actually how big is the file? is it less then 2MB?  And are you just not seeing the file, but the code works?  I ask because if you use `fopen('php://temp', $f)` it wont create a file if it's under 2MB it just stores it in memory.  I'm not sure if this applies to uploads but it could.  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Yes the file is less than 2MB just 91kb. I validate the seize in the code. The code doesn't work. On the move_uploaded_file line I have the : there was an error uploading your file So that means the result is false.

Comment: it's possible your destination does not exit.  I always use full paths like `$target_dir = __DIR__."/assets/uploads/"`;  Otherwise just looking at it nothing jumps out.  You could check `is_dir($target_dir)`, move can fail if the source or destination folder dosn't exist.  As I was saying you cannot rely on the file actually showing up in `tmp`.  It's not meant to hold the file after the request has finished, it could get removed is what I am saying.